# How to Disable Wireless Network Connection Notification Balloon?

Tags: c++, windows, wifi, balloon, wlanapi

I want to programmatically disable the notification I get when I connect to a wireless network. I know there is a way to disable ALL notifications (see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/disable-notification-balloons-in-xp/)) but is there a way to only disable the one issued by Windows wireless Manager (i.e. wlanapi.dll).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, except in Windows 7 when it's available. (It apparently includes a much more configurable tray-program manager).

Answer (score 0):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
New \ DWORD
EnableBalloonTips
Hexadecimal
0
```